# WordPress - Requested URL Not Found

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<a href="where.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Where Are We</a>
```

Trying to do a nav bar link in my `header.php`, but getting a 404, despite the file being in the same directory as my `index.php`. Also the `index.php` requires the `header.php` file. **Not too familiar with WordPress**.

[image: FTP Directory]

Comment: What you are doing is wrong , If you need to access a php filee in wordpress, for eg where.php should be in the root directory,  It should not be inside your theme.

Comment: Ah. So only my index.php should be in the theme directory? Where is the root directory (sorry for asking what seems a simple question!)

Comment: Root directory is the place where wp-content folder resides.. Also  more question..what is the purpose of where.php , Once you add this file to root folder, You can accessit only through http://yourdomain.com/where.php .. Also you cannot directly use any wordpress functions inside that where.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add your link like this

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_file_uri('where.php'));?>">where are we?</a>
```

the function `get_theme_file_uri` generates url to the theme folder.